# jQuery using code to switch between faq answers

Tags: jquery

I feel like I am going out of my mind with this! I'm writing a set of Frequently Asked Questions, but I only want one answer to be displayed at a time...

Here's my code...

```
function show_response(id)
{
//loop to hide any open responses
for(i = 1; i <= $('.faq_response').length; i++)
    {
    if($('#faq'+i) != id) //This line was missing the $ and brackets but that didn't solve the problem.
        $('#faq'+i).css('display','none');
    }
//show or hide the response depending on its current state
$('#'+id).toggle();
}
```

Currently if I click on a question, the response shows up. If I then click on a different question, the previous response hides and the new response appears. If I click on a question where the answer is already showing, it should hide but it doesn't do anything.

If I block out the loop bit of code, the toggle part works fine.

Hoping someone else can see where I've gone wrong before I end up with no hair!

Thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: This should be easy to figure out if you use a debugger like Firebug. Unfortunately I'm on an iPad right now...

Comment: I am using firebug and it isn't telling me anything is wrong!

Comment: It should show that you're hiding every element in your for loop... Then toggling one of them afterwards. Put a breakpoint in the for loop. There are so many better ways to do this with jQuery... but I can't type them fast enough on an iPad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `#` in your if statement like this:

```
function show_response(id) {
    for (i = 1; i <= $('.faq_response').length; i++) {
        var s = 'faq' + i;
        if (s != id) { 
            $('#' + s).css('display','none');
        }
    }
    $('#' + id).toggle();
}
```

You're hiding every element in your for loop then toggling one of them afterwards.

Presumeably none of your ids actually contain a `#` symbol.

Comment: I might be wrong but I thought you use a dot if a class, and # if an id. Took away the # as suggested and now firebug is telling me there are syntax errors!

Comment: @Paul - I meant remove the pound sign from the line where you compare the id to a string. You're comparing the raw id to an id that contains a pound sign... Which none of your ids contain. Just use the answer provided by Jason (and upvote mine).

Comment: I am so confused, there is no £ sign!?!?

Comment: By pound sign I mean the `#` symbol. (That's what I've always heard it called in America). I edited my answer to provide the exact code you should use.

Comment: I am gobsmacked, doing it like you've done it has got it working. I didnt know you could do that :/ Thought it had to be with a # surrounded by brackets and then with a $ before the whole lot. So yeah, weorks as wanted now, thanks very much.

Comment: @Paul - The `#` symbol only has that meaning in a jQuery selector.  You just want to compare a simple string to the actual id passed to the function (which will not contain a `#` symbol). I edited my answer to make it more expressive.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.faq_response').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().hide();
    $(this).toggle();
})
```

should do the trick, but one would have to see the actual markup...

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop.

your html could be:

```
<div class="answer" id="foo">
```

Then hide em all and show the one you want:

```
$(".answer").hide();
$("#" + id).show().click(function(){$("#" + id).hide()});
```

Probably a better syntax for that, but you get the idea.

Comment: The problem with this is with the logic. If a response is open, I would want it to close if clicked again. Instead when clicked, it will close and then open again.

Comment: I don't think this will work if you continue to click on answers you've already seen.  Every time you click on them after the first time, they will get hidden...